# Will simultaneity bias occur if I use VAR to test the linkages between monetary shocks, interest rates, and inflation?

Tags: econometrics, structural-equation-modeling, vector-autoregression, macroeconomics

I am writing an undergraduate paper and my goal is to investigate the liquidity effect. That is, I want to determine if expansions in monetary policy reduce interest rates.

Initially, I wanted to create a SEM because economic theory says that monetary aggregates (such as M1) are jointly determined with interest rates. However, in studying the literature for this paper, I've discovered that many researchers estimate a VAR with interest rates, economic output, money supply, and inflation as dependent variables.

Many of these authors also do not mention anything about simultaneity bias.

So, my question is: do we need to worry about simultaneity bias when studying interest rates? If not, then why?